# Оптимальные опции для x86 GCC (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Использую проект [AdvanceCOMP](http://www.advancemame.it/download.html).
Возник вопрос, как можно увеличить производительность данного проекта при компиляции.

Сейчас я делаю так:

```
CFLAGS='-Ofast -flto' CXXFLAGS='-Ofast -flto' LDFLAGS='-static -flto' ./configure
make
```

Справка из ./configure -h

```
`configure' configures AdvanceCOMP 1.20 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/advancecomp]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --disable-largefile     omit support for large files
  --enable-bzip2       Use the bzip2 compression
  --enable-valgrind       enable the use of valgrind in testing
  --enable-debug          enable debugging

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  TESTENV     Test environment

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

Report bugs to the package provider.
AdvanceCOMP home page: <http://www.advancemame.it>.
```

Comment: Рискну предположить что оптимизация самого кода даст гораздо больший прирост производительности...

Comment: (1) попробуйте profile guided optimization (`-fprofile-*`). (2) попробуйте лучше соптимизировать алгоритмы, перепишите O(n^2) на O(log n) (неужели все алгоритмы уже улучшены до невозможности?). (3) используйте профайлер, чтобы найти узкие места, и соптимизируйте их вручную. Не надейтесь, что низкоуровневая оптимизация компилятора лучше высокоуровневой оптимизации, которую сделаете вы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Флаг `-Ofast` не рекомендуется, так как считается небезопасным (включает оптимизации, нарушающие совместимость со стандартом).

Есть куча разных флагов, но использовать их стоит в зависимости от целевой архитектуры и с умом.

Я довольно часто использую следующий набор с целью получить максимальную производительность приложения на архитектуре x86:

> -march=native -O3 -mfpmath=both -funroll-loops -fopenmp -floop-parallelize-all -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL -D_GLIBCXX_MERGESORT

Они не требуют вмешательства пользователя в код программы.

Comment: Вы не могли помочь еще с mozjpeg. я делаю так
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"
make
Как можно увеличить производительность?

Comment: Если не трудно напишите на почту lorents!7@mail.ru

Comment: @lorents я плохо знаком с CMake. Вам лучше задать новый вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: Понял! Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте OpenMP версию STL. Достаточно добавить флаг -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL и установить необходимые для OpenMP библиотеки, и все стандартные алгоритмы будут заменены на паралельные.

Подробней тут: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_using.html

Попробуйте еще сборку под С++11.

А так, конечно надо профайлить код.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Я как раз думал об OpenMP, вы не подскажите, Как его установить на MSYS2?

Comment: Возможно ничего не надо будет ставить дополнительно, поддержка OpenMP завист от версии компилятора. Тут есть небольшой пример тестовой програмки под openmp и как его собирать под Windows http://www.ipd.uni-karlsruhe.de/multicore/research/download/HowToGuide-OpenMP.pdf

Comment: Мне выдает такую ошибку. $ ./configure  -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL                                              configure: error: unrecognized option: `-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL'
Try `./configure --help' for more information

Comment: Надо во флаги ставить: CFLAGS='-Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL' CXXFLAGS='-Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL'

Comment: Спасибо большое! Пойду тестировать скоросто работы! Подскажите, как правильней:$ CFLAGS='-Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL' CXXFLAGS='-Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL' LDFLAGS='-static -Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL' ./configure
или CFLAGS='-Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL' CXXFLAGS='-Ofast -flto -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL' LDFLAGS='-static' ./configure

Comment: C и CXX FLAGS опции компилятора, LDFLAGS линковщика, ему хватит '-static'